# Exclude directory and file from case sensitive RedirectMatch rule

Tags: apache, redirect

On my website all pagenames can be found at /bin/view/ and start with a capital letter. All subdirectories or other files in the document root start with something else.

The following rule in my Apache configuration takes care of that:

```
RedirectMatch ^/([A-Z].*) http://www.example.com/bin/view/$1
```

Now I'd like to exclude the following URL from the `RedirectMatch`:

http://www.example.com/Directory/File

There's no /bin/view/, and Directory and File both start with a capital letter. This cannot be changed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing the line to:

```
RedirectMatch ^(?!\/Directory)\/([A-Z].*) http://example.com/bin/view/$1
```